# Добавить значение в ключ и чтобы оно индексировалось php

Tags: php, массивы

Вот есть у меня массив, в нём ключ 'name'. В name соответственно разные значения и когда я вывожу массив, то все элементы индексируются и записываются как мне надо(красным маркером). Мне нужно как-то через array_unshift и array_push вставить в массив разные значения, чтобы они были как я обозначил красным маркером, а не как синим. Можно ли это как-то сделать? Я видел там люди через array_merge делали или просто делали новую переменную и через плюсик конкатенацию делали, но это не то немного. Возможно оно конечно и так, но может я просто туплю, и не могу простое сделать...(php недавно начал изучать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вставляйте не `"клубника"` а `['name' => "клубника"]`

Comment: мне нужно добавить именно в конкретный массив(например в $fruits), снизу я объединяю три массива в один и вывожу, но у меня не выводится то что я добавил через array_unshfit, так как я не задал ему ключ name, и я пытаюсь понять как ключ ему тоже добавить

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/QNP2PTwhg9QJXS9ZU7Q9LQ

Comment: спасибо большое